# Gradient background color in css from top left corner to bottom right

Tags: css, sass, background

I'm working on a webpage, and I want to give it a background color with a gradient. From purple to light color.

However, the css is not working. If someone can let me know what am I missing and why is not working?

The background color is the same one as in this codepen. https://codepen.io/alexboffey/pen/NAkQLE?limit=all&page=2&q=calculator
Here the developer used scss. 
here's the css

```
$purp: #542437;
$gold: #CDB380;

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, $purp 0%, $gold 100%) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you put the hex in instead of the $purp and $gold it works. Can it be an issue with sass not compiling properly?

```css
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #542437 0%, #CDB380 100%) 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>

</body>
```

Comment: yeah you can also do the color eg: red, yellow... but I wanted to see how variable declaration work as in the link provided above

Comment: If you put this into codepen and set SCSS it works completely fine https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/bazONj so I reckon it's an issue with compiling Sass

Answer (score 0):

So there's apparently a lot of work you have to do before SCSS will work in a local environment: https://medium.com/@ricardozea/sass-for-beginners-the-friendliest-guide-about-how-to-install-use-sass-on-windows-22ff4a32c1f7. Also, you have to save the CSS file with a .scss extension, I believe.
Here's a fiddle using straight hexadecimal color codes `#542437` and `#CDB380` in case anyone is curious: https://jsfiddle.net/ss20wh3f/2/